# How to detect if a listview has an adapter set

Tags: android, listview

I want to know when my listview has no adapter set on it. I mean, is there a way to know when I have called setListAdapter(mAdapter); without a condition on my code?

I want to add a header to my listview, but just the first time as:

```
if(getListView().getAdapter() != null){
    WWDisplayUtils.addHeaderButton(mTaxis, mAirport, AirportDetailsTaxi.this);
    setListAdapter(mTaxiA);
}
else    
   mTaxiA.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But is not doing what I want.

Comment: What do you mean, "without condition"? By it's very nature you question seems to imply that there a different conditions you Activity might be in and you therefor want to respond differently to those different conditions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
if(getListView().getAdapter() != null)
```

be

```
if(getListView().getAdapter() == null)
```

If you've already set a header or footer view, getAdapter() will return a [WrapperListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/WrapperListAdapter.html) instead of the one you set with setListAdapter()

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just call [getAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getAdapter%28%29) and see if its null or at least see if it's not equal to what you thought it should be? So like this:

```
if(mListView.getAdapter() != mAdapter){
  //do one thing
}
else{
  //do another thing
}
```

Comment: He does mention "without a condition on my code", whatever that means!

Comment: @Ricky That's why I asked him for clarification in a comment on his question. It the phrase "without a condition on my code" doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Hello guys, I meant without a boolean member variable, to check it. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Call [getListAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListAdapter%28%29)?

Comment: He said he's calling `setListAdapter()` which implies `ListActivity`.